# How to simplify this code in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have following code for 3 DataGridView Controls in my VB.NET winform application. How can I simplify this code?

```
    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With

    With DataGridView2
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With

    With DataGridView3
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could;

```
For Each o As DataGridView In New DataGridView() {DataGridView1, DataGridView2, DataGridView3}
    o.Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
    o.AutoResizeColumns()
Next
```

Comment: Even shorter: For Each o As DataGridView In {DataGridView1, DataGridView2, DataGridView3}

Answer (score 4):

Apologies if this isn't valid VB.Net:

```
AddColumn(DataGridView1)
AddColumn(DataGridView2)
AddColumn(DataGridView3)

Private Sub AddColumn(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    dgv.Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
    dgv.AutoResizeColumns()
End Sub
```

Comment: You could refactor this Sub further to pass a column name and task name as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public NotInheritable Class GridViewHelper

Public Shared Function BuildDataGridView(view as DataGridView) as DataGridView
With View
    .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName") 
    .AutoResizeColumns()
End With
Return view
End Function

End Class
```

Of course, you can add TryCast() and so on to make sure the correct object is passed in etc.